# Oracle where and index

Tags: oracle, indexing, where-clause

I have such a problem, here is the data structure I have

```
create table tab (
     id_tab integer not null,
     val1 integer,
     val2 integer,
     val3 integer,
     val4 integer,
     val5 integer,
     val6 integer,
     val7 integer,
     val8 integer,
     val9 integer,
     CONSTRAINT tab_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_tab)
  );
  
  create index val1_index on tab (val1);
  create index val2_index on tab (val2);
  create index val3_index on tab (val3);
  create index val4_index on tab (val4);
  create index val5_index on tab (val5);
  create index val6_index on tab (val6);
  create index val7_index on tab (val7);
  create index val8_index on tab (val8);
  create index val9_index on tab (val9);

  create procedure test1 as
  begin
    for x in 1..10000
    loop
      insert into tab(id_tab, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9)
      values ((select nvl(max(id_tab), 0) + 1 from tab), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)),
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)));
    end loop;
  end;
  /

BEGIN
test1;
-- for my example, to find value:
insert into tab (id_tab, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9) 
values(-1, 3, 1, null, 5, 2, 1, 9, null, 1);
END;
/
```

Now I'm looking for the result

```
SELECT * FROM tab
where 
(decode(val1, 3, 1) = 1) and -- it's like: (val1 = 3 or (val1 is null and 3 is null) 
(decode(val2, 1, 1) = 1) and 
(decode(val3, null, 1) = 1) and -- it's like: (val1 = null or (val1 is null and null is null)
(decode(val4, 5, 1) = 1) and
(decode(val5, 2, 1) = 1) and
(decode(val6, 1, 1) = 1) and
(decode(val7, 9, 1) = 1) and
(decode(val8, null, 1) = 1) and
(decode(val9, 1, 1) = 1)
```

And I have an expected outcome:

[image]

The problem is that I have about a million to find such combinations and it takes about an hour, the question is whether it is possible to use other indexes or otherwise to construct a query (where) to make the search for such combinations time-efficient?

here's the example:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ed77f058517197d4468e143f9deab3e1

DB: Oracle 11 Standard Edition One

Comment: You can try FBIs (function based indexes), one for each of the `decode()`s, if their arguments are fixed.

Comment: I don't understand. `decode(val1, 3, 1) = 1` is exactly equivalent to `val1 = 3`, so why are you writing it in such a complicated way - which also prevents the use of an index on `val1`? If that is not your actual query - if the real query is more complicated, and that use of `decode` does serve some purpose - then show us the real query fragment, not a mock-up that makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: The `3` is an input paramater, so it can be `NULL`. The *real problem* here is - the predicate should behave as `NULL = NULL` @mathguy

Comment: decode(val1, :x, 1) = 1 when val1 is null and :x is null then 1 or val1 = :x then 1. (decode(val1, :x, 1) = 1) = (val1 = :x or (val1 is null and x is null))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a function on an index after you create it, it will be supressed by that function and become useless(like this one `(decode(val1, 3, 1) = 1)`).
On the other hand you should not use that much index. It is not a best practice and you should know that. Every index you have created has a cost on your disk.

If you insist using indexes you should consider creating a function which gets some inputs and decode them on your terms then create your indexes with using that function.

[Function based indexes](https://logicalread.com/oracle-11-g-function-based-indexes-mc02/#.XwnDppMzbAw)

Comment: That's what I did. I added an extra index column to one column. (Look above) ;)

Comment: Then again you should not use `DECODE` on them in your `WHERE` clause. This is the one place you supressed your indexes with `DECODE`. You should implement it into your `TAB`function.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should have not created any of those indexes at all, because your where clause is affecting all columns. Indexes are quite effective when your where clause is looking for a specific column or columns, but not when all the columns in your table are part of the predicate. In this case the CBO ( Cost Based Optimizer ) will always use a table full scan.

Let me show you an example with your data model

```
SQL> create table tab_example (
     id_tab integer not null,
     val1 integer,
     val2 integer,
     val3 integer,
     val4 integer,
     val5 integer,
     val6 integer,
     val7 integer,
     val8 integer,
     val9 integer,
     CONSTRAINT tab_example_pk PRIMARY KEY (id_tab)
  )
/

Table created.

SQL> create index val1_index on tab_example (val1);
  create index val2_index on tab_example (val2);
  create index val3_index on tab_example (val3);
  create index val4_index on tab_example (val4);
  create index val5_index on tab_example (val5);
  create index val6_index on tab_example (val6);
  create index val7_index on tab_example (val7);
  create index val8_index on tab_example (val8);
  create index val9_index on tab_example (val9);
  
  Index created.

SQL>
Index created.

SQL>
Index created.

SQL>
Index created.

SQL>
Index created.

SQL>
Index created.

SQL>
Index created.

SQL>
Index created.

SQL>

Index created.
```

I create the procreate with one million rows in the scope

```
SQL> create or replace procedure test1 as
begin
    for x in 1..1000000
    loop
      insert into tab_example(id_tab, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9)
      values ((select nvl(max(id_tab), 0) + 1 from tab_example), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)),
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)), 
              decode(round(dbms_random.value(0,2)), 1, null, dbms_random.value(1,9)));
    end loop;
  end;
  /

Procedure created.

SQL> set timing on 
SQL>  begin
  2  test1;
  3  insert into tab_example (id_tab, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9)
  4  values(-1, 3, 1, null, 5, 2, 1, 9, null, 1);
  5* end;
/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:08:09.34
```

As you can see the execution of the procedure takes a lot of time, mostly because there are 9 indexes involved in the operation. Keep in mind that any DML operation against a table has to do the same for the indexes. In your case those indexes are not offering any help, in regards of your query, because like I said your predicate is looking to each and every column in your table.

Let's calculate statistics and see the explain plan of your query

```
SQL> exec dbms_stats.gather_table_stats( 'MYUSER' , 'TAB_EXAMPLE' );

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:04.19

SQL> set autotrace traceonly explain
SQL> SELECT * FROM tab_example
where
  2    3  (decode(val1, 3, 1) = 1) and -- it's like: (val1 = 3 or (val1 is null and 3 is null)
  4  (decode(val2, 1, 1) = 1) and
(decode(val3, null, 1) = 1) and -- it's like: (val1 = null or (val1 is null and null is null)
  5    6  (decode(val4, 5, 1) = 1) and
(decode(val5, 2, 1) = 1) and
(decode(val6, 1, 1) = 1) and
(decode(val7, 9, 1) = 1) and
  7    8    9   10  (decode(val8, null, 1) = 1) and
 11  (decode(val9, 1, 1) = 1);
Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

Execution Plan
----------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2592949226

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation         | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT  |             |     1 |    23 |   709   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  TABLE ACCESS FULL| TAB_EXAMPLE |     1 |    23 |   709   (3)| 00:00:01 |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(DECODE("VAL1",3,1)=1 AND DECODE("VAL2",1,1)=1 AND
              DECODE("VAL4",5,1)=1 AND DECODE("VAL5",2,1)=1 AND DECODE("VAL6",1,1)=1
              AND DECODE("VAL7",9,1)=1 AND DECODE("VAL9",1,1)=1 AND
              DECODE(TO_CHAR("VAL3"),NULL,1)=1 AND DECODE(TO_CHAR("VAL8"),NULL,1)=1)
```

In my case the query takes almost nothing, and the execution plan is the right one given the predicate information. I am checking each and every single column, therefore a FULL TABLE ACCESS is better in this case.

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM tab_example
where
  2    3  (decode(val1, 3, 1) = 1) and -- it's like: (val1 = 3 or (val1 is null and 3 is null)
(decode(val2, 1, 1) = 1) and
(decode(val3, null, 1) = 1) and -- it's like: (val1 = null or (val1 is null and null is null)
(decode(val4, 5, 1) = 1) and
  4    5    6    7  (decode(val5, 2, 1) = 1) and
(decode(val6, 1, 1) = 1) and
(decode(val7, 9, 1) = 1) and
  8    9   10  (decode(val8, null, 1) = 1) and
(decode(val9, 1, 1) = 1) 11  ;

    ID_TAB       VAL1       VAL2       VAL3       VAL4       VAL5       VAL6       VAL7       VAL8       VAL9
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
        -1          3          1                     5          2          1          9                     1

Elapsed: 00:00:00.21
```

If I remove the indexes (except the enforce index used by the primary key)  let's see how much time I need for making the insert

```
SQL> declare
begin
for i in ( select index_name from dba_indexes where table_name = 'TAB_EXAMPLE' and index_name like 'VAL%' )
loop
        execute immediate ' drop index '||i.index_name||' ' ;
end loop;
end;
/
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.32

SQL> truncate table TAB_EXAMPLE ;

Table truncated.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.17

SQL> begin
test1;
insert into tab_example (id_tab, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9)
values(-1, 3, 1, null, 5, 2, 1, 9, null, 1);
end;
/  2    3    4    5    6

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:02:41.01
```

**Summary:** Proper indexing is a good exercise when you build a physical data model. Indexing all columns is not a good option and a poor decision. There are situations in like perhaps you would need a IOT ( Index Organized Table ) but I don't see the case here, neither to use so many useless indexes.

Hope it helps a bit!

Answer (score 0):

I added an additional text column called "HASH" to the "TAB" table.

I counted it out like this:

```
VAL1||'*'||VAL2||'*'||val3||'*'||val4||'*'||val5||'*'||val6||'*'||val7||'*'||val8||'*'||val9
```

I indexed the text column "HASH", working time was reduced from an hour to a few seconds, because the search follows one index... Is there a problem here somewhere?

Comment: No problem, I was going to suggest this but you found it yourself already. Of course, you must rewrite your `WHERE` clause too, to "hash" the input variable. (By the way, don't say "hash" in this context, "list aggregate" would be better; hash has a technical meaning different from what you are doing). Caveat - if you have too many columns and the inputs have too many digits, your concatenated string may become longer than 4000 characters, which would be a problem.

Comment: The *one* problem @mathguy here is that you rely on the current  NLS setting for the *number to string* conversion. This may change wich would have a fatal effect on the search. So I'd suggest to convert explicitely such as `to_char(val1,'S0999')||'x'||to_char(val2,'S0999')..`. As a delimiter you should not use a character that can appear in the number (`-` will can cause no problems, but could be *confusing* if you have negative numbers).

Comment: That's what I thought, and I applied the "*", I'm about to correct.

Comment: This is it. Bravo @TomaszTomzik